# Using SignalR Hubs, connection is lost after some time - why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr, keep-alive

In my SignalR app, callbacks are fired as expected on a page.  If the page is left for some time, callbacks are no longer invoked on that page until it is refreshed.

I suspect that this could be due to the site's session expiring (using a client's session ID to invoke a client notification).

I read [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/168) about the `KeepAlive` functionality and can see some references to it in the SignalR code.  I am unclear if a client-side keep-alive needs to be implemented, and if so, how?

Comment: Did you actually solve the issue?  I am trying to figure this out right now.  If you did, would you mind posing specifics about what you did?

Comment: this issue may have been resolved with v0.5.2 - try it out, as I don't see the issue occurring now.  Also check in at http://jabbr.net/#/rooms/signalr and see what they have to say.

Comment: I am on the current version of SignalR, I am using it in a WebView on Android and it stops working after a while.  I found a solution last night by setting KeepAlive on the ConfigurationManager in SignalR.  Now it keeps the connection open on the client, but I have not fully tested it yet.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Are you sure that session is expiring? As long as you don't touch session this shouldn't be the reason. Is your site authenticated? Could it be that authentication ticket times out? Are your hubs authenticated?

Comment: Also,the article you are referring to is not about server session but the signalr connectivity. From what I have understood about signalr is that it tries to stay away from sessions, caches etc in order to maintain scalability.

Comment: Do you have any concurrent requests other than yours? If not I can assume this is happening because of application pool recycling... Can you check event viewer to see if this is happening? I think signalr does not prevent app pool shutdown so, no requests ... App is going to sleep. If that s the case, you must actively change application pool not to recycle... Or force it like stilgar proposed but the later will add some unnecessary traffic to your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't made any experiments or checked the documentation but your assumption makes sense. SignalR does not support session for various good reasons. If it does not support reading from the session then it is reasonable to expect that it will not refresh the Session expiration time. However if you really need to use Session ID as the client ID (which you should not) then implementing a kind of keep alive is easy. Just write some JS to call the server (a Session enabled HTTP handler for example) in the simplest manner without doing any work. It will serve only to refresh the Session expiration time.

Comment: In our case, I'm not using the sessionID as the client ID.  I'm letting SingalR issue them as it does - new client ID per page load.  I have a hub data structure that retains the session data, but what you are suggesting makes sense.  We are still doing more testing.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events

```
  $.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
      alert('disconnected')
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert('reconnecting')
        $.connection.hub.start();
      }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
    });
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and KeepAlive? Will this continue to reconnect regardless of how long the server is down for.. etc?