# SignalR - Works when deployed to Server, but stops after a few hours (MVC)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

EDIT: Look at the bottom of this post for updates.

My SignalR implementation works perfectly on my local system. But when I deployed it out to my server it doesnt seem to work. Its an MVC project.

My signalR jQuery is as follows:

```
var clientHub = $.connection.gamehub;

$(function () {

    var signalRHubInitialized = false;

    var image = $("#Ico");

    var count = 0;

    initializeSignalRHubStore();

    function initializeSignalRHubStore() {

        if (signalRHubInitialized)
            return;

        try {

            clientHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {
                if (message === "Refresh")
                    reloadIndexPartial();
            };

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                clientHub.server.initialize($("#NotifierEntity").val());
                signalRHubInitialized = true;
            });

        } catch (err) {
            signalRHubInitialized = false;
        }
    };

    function reloadIndexPartial() {
        //$.post('@(Url.Action("LivePartial", "Scrim", null, Request.Url.Scheme))')
        var id = $("#SeriesDetail_Id").val();
        $.post('/Scrim/LivePartial/' + id)
            .done(function (response) {
                try {
                    count = count + 1;
                    var favicon = new Favico({
                        animation: 'pop',
                        image: image
                    });
                    favicon.badge(count);
                }
                catch (exception) {

                }
                $("#summary-wrapper").html("");
                $("#summary-wrapper").html(response);
                if (!signalRHubInitialized)
                    initializeSignalRHubStore();
            });
    };
});
```

I downloaded Fiddler to see what was going on:

/signalr/hubs returned a HTTP200

```
GET http://sitename.com/signalr/hubs HTTP/1.1
Host: sitename.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://sitename.com/scrim/Live/2835
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.1342148401.1475084375; _gid=GA1.2.2092796788.1503865866
```

negotiate returned at HTTP200

```
GET http://sitename.com/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22gamehub%22%7D%5D&_=1505151041506 HTTP/1.1
Host: sitename.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://sitename.com/scrim/Live/2835
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.1342148401.1475084375; _gid=GA1.2.2092796788.1503865866
```

connect, didnt return anything

```
GET http://sitename.com/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=S8rqz2NPvVSJxbS1%2FpLm7yHTinGHWK1SnAwh8IfYA%2BP7nVb9RV%2FJzSFsf8Q%2BTv6Z%2Fae%2FIoZKlHKyeTxaEn3obg%2FVViYTB5HZxnrvKvtBZtQopvGPdj1i4o8Z9wGlCz3%2F&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22gamehub%22%7D%5D&tid=10 HTTP/1.1
Host: sitename.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://sitename.com/scrim/Live/2835
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.1342148401.1475084375; _gid=GA1.2.2092796788.1503865866
```

start returned a HTTP200

```
GET http://sitename.com/signalr/start?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=S8rqz2NPvVSJxbS1%2FpLm7yHTinGHWK1SnAwh8IfYA%2BP7nVb9RV%2FJzSFsf8Q%2BTv6Z%2Fae%2FIoZKlHKyeTxaEn3obg%2FVViYTB5HZxnrvKvtBZtQopvGPdj1i4o8Z9wGlCz3%2F&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22gamehub%22%7D%5D&_=1505151041507 HTTP/1.1
Host: sitename.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://sitename.com/scrim/Live/2835
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.1342148401.1475084375; _gid=GA1.2.2092796788.1503865866
```

Send returned a HTTP200

```
POST http://sitename.com/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=S8rqz2NPvVSJxbS1%2FpLm7yHTinGHWK1SnAwh8IfYA%2BP7nVb9RV%2FJzSFsf8Q%2BTv6Z%2Fae%2FIoZKlHKyeTxaEn3obg%2FVViYTB5HZxnrvKvtBZtQopvGPdj1i4o8Z9wGlCz3%2F&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22gamehub%22%7D%5D HTTP/1.1
Host: sitename.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2227
Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://sitename.com
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://sitename.com/scrim/Live/2835
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.1342148401.1475084375; _gid=GA1.2.2092796788.1503865866

data=%7B%22H%22%3A%22gamehub%22%2C%22M%22%3A%22Initialize%22%2C%22A%22%3A%5B%22%7B%5C%22SqlQuery%5C%22%3A%5C%22SELECT+%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++%5BExtent1%5D.%5BId%5D+AS+%5BId%5D%2C+%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++%5BExtent1%5D.%5BGameGuid%5D+AS+%5BGameGuid%5D%2C+%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++%5BExtent1%5D.%5BDate%5D+AS+%5BDate%5D%2C+%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++%5BExtent1%5D.%5BTeamOneScore%5D+AS+%5BTeamOneScore%5D%2C+%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++%5BExtent1%5D.%5BTeamZeroScore%5D+AS+%5BTeamZeroScore%5D%2C+%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++%5BExtent1%5D.%5BTeamOneId%5D+AS+%5BTeamOneId%5D%2C+%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++%5BExtent1%5D.%5BTeamZeroId%5D+AS+%5BTeamZeroId%5D%2C+%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++%5BExtent1%5D.%5BGameVariantId%5D+AS+%5BGameVariantId%5D%2C+%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++%5BExtent1%5D.%5BMapId%5D+AS+%5BMapId%5D%2C+%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++%5BExtent1%5D.%5BDuration%5D+AS+%5BDuration%5D%2C+%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++%5BExtent1%5D.%5BSeriesId%5D+AS+%5BSeriesId%5D%2C+%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++%5BExtent1%5D.%5BResult%5D+AS+%5BResult%5D%2C+%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++%5BExtent1%5D.%5BActive%5D+AS+%5BActive%5D%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++FROM+%5Bdbo%5D.%5BGame%5D+AS+%5BExtent1%5D%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn++++WHERE+(%5BExtent1%5D.%5BActive%5D+%3D+1)+AND+(%5BExtent1%5D.%5BSeriesId%5D+%3D+%40p__linq__0)%5C%22%2C%5C%22SqlConnectionString%5C%22%3A%5C%22Data+Source%3DWIN-1J1JAEOEU33%3BInitial+Catalog%3DSiteName%3BIntegrated+Security%3DTrue%3BMultipleActiveResultSets%3DTrue%3B%5C%22%2C%5C%22SqlParameters%5C%22%3A%5B%7B%5C%22CompareInfo%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22XmlSchemaCollectionDatabase%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22XmlSchemaCollectionOwningSchema%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22XmlSchemaCollectionName%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22DbType%5C%22%3A11%2C%5C%22LocaleId%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22ParameterName%5C%22%3A%5C%22p__linq__0%5C%22%2C%5C%22Precision%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22Scale%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22SqlDbType%5C%22%3A8%2C%5C%22SqlValue%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22IsNull%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22Value%5C%22%3A2835%7D%2C%5C%22UdtTypeName%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22TypeName%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22Value%5C%22%3A2835%2C%5C%22Direction%5C%22%3A1%2C%5C%22IsNullable%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22Offset%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22Size%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22SourceColumn%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22SourceColumnNullMapping%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22SourceVersion%5C%22%3A512%7D%5D%7D%22%5D%2C%22I%22%3A0%7D
```

I have added this to my web config:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
```

Looking through all the responses it seems that everything is working correctly but the page Im on is not being updated when a new entry has been added to the database.

On my local development system my project is set up using IIS it works flawlessly.

Could anyone point me in the right direction please.

EDIT: I have got it working on the server now. But it seems that it works right after it has been deployed for a few hours. Then after that it seems to stop working. So I have to assume that the signalr connection is being disposed at some stage and now getting reinstated?

Here is my RegisterServices class:

```
private static IContainer RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    builder.RegisterType<ContextEntities>()
           .As<DbContext>()
           .InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>()
        .As<IDbFactory>()
        .InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>()
        .As<IUnitOfWork>()
        .InstancePerRequest();

    // Services

    builder.RegisterType<MembershipService>()
    .As<IMembershipService>()
    .InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<CacheService>()
    .As<ICacheService>()
    .InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<GameHub>().ExternallyOwned();

    Container = builder.Build();

    return Container;
}
```

Here is a page where signalr is used: http://halodatahive.com/Scrim/Live/2845

I seem to be losing reference to the signalr connection after a few hours after a deployment.

EDIT: If I recycle my APP POOL the page with signalR starts working again.

Comment: Did you check the IIS/Webserver Logs? If your Application crashes on a Windows Server, there should also be a entry in the Event Viewer... Did you implemented a Application Log?

Comment: I will check the logs now. If the application was to crash would it not restart and call the app_start code again?

Comment: Its seems like the application was fine. There doesnt seem to be any crashes.

Comment: When your application stops working, what will the application return? Are there any 400er, 500er, a connection timeout or something else? What happens in the Network Tab of the Developer Console in Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: The signalr is part of a web application. I dont know what the application returns if it fails. There doesnt seem to be any failing on the signalr pages in regards to signalr. Here is one of the pages in question: http://halodatahive.com/Scrim/Live/2845

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154418/discussion-between-noren-and-bad-dub).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676270/using-signalr-hubs-connection-is-lost-after-some-time-why

Comment: What version of SignalR?

Comment: Its version 2.2.0.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I ended up using to resolve the issue. It seems that after around 1 hour it was getting disconnected some how. I put this code in a few hours ago and it still seems to be working. Thanks to @Noren for all their help in chat earlier!

EDIT: This did not seem to solve the problem unfortunately.

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.connection.hub.start();
    }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```

EDIT: Thought I would give an update as to how I got this working. Instead of using `SqlDependency` to trigger the SignalR I just called `Clients.All.broadcastMessage("Refresh");` on the scheduled task I have running on the server when `_unitOfWork.Commit()` was called.

Something was causing SqlDependency to stop working and the only way to get it to pick it up again was to recycle the app pool.

Comment: You've probably resolved the issue now... anyhow I use the approach above along side long-polling transport type and all seem to work well. I think the take home is understanding when the application pool goes idle. For me long-polling allows it to stay alive.

Comment: I think I have solved it with my answer above but there is an embedded stream on the same page which throws JS errors for fun when the stream is live. So Im hoping that its these errors thats causing the problem now. But Im not sure yet.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen something like this before. In my case it was RabbitMQ events that were lost because IIS was spinning down the application.

Is your application is not being hit very frequently? IIS has a tendency to spin down applications that it doesn't think it needs in order to save resources. That might be why it only stops working after a few hours and you can recycle to bring it back up.

[See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993968/how-to-prevent-iis-from-shutting-down-web-site-when-not-in-use)

Comment: I had tried this and set the interval to 0 but the problem was still occurring unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

> first add **Hubs** folder and `NotificationsHubs.cs` in root

[image: Hubs]

in NotificationsHubs.cs

```
[HubName("NotificationsHubs")]
public class NotificationsHubs : Hub
{

    public static Thread NotificationsThread;
    public void Send(string token, string UserAgent, string IP)
    {
        var serverVars = Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Request.ServerVariables;
        string SignalRIp = serverVars["REMOTE_ADDR"];

        string T = Context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToLower();
        if ((T == cryptClass.crypt.Decrypt(UserAgent))  && (SignalRIp == cryptClass.crypt.Decrypt(IP)))
        {
            var connection = SignalRConnections.Connections.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Token == Guid.Parse(token));
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Context = this.Context;
            }

            if (NotificationsThread == null || !NotificationsThread.IsAlive)
            {
               NotificationsThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(NotificationsCheck));
                NotificationsThread.Start();
            }
        }
```

**`NotificationsCheck` is custom function**

---

in `NotificationController`

```
public ActionResult Notifications()
{
    NotificationsModule.messageBL = _messageBL;
    long UserID = GetCurrentUser();
    Notification _Notification = new Notification();
    _Notification.GetToken = SignalRConnections.GetToken(UserID);
    _Notification.UserAgent = cryptClass.crypt.Encrypt(Request.UserAgent.ToLower());
    _Notification.IP = cryptClass.crypt.Encrypt(Request.UserHostAddress);
    return View(_Notification);
}
```

---

in `Notifications.cshtml`  view

add this JS file

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js")"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>

$(function () {

    // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
    var chat = $.connection.NotificationsHubs;
    // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
    chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (Title, Body, Icon) {
        // Add the message to the page.
        notifyMe(Title, Body, Icon);
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        chat.server.send('@Model.GetToken', '@Model.UserAgent', '@Model.IP');
        $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
            // Call the Send method on the hub.
            chat.server.send();
        });
    });
});
```

**`notifyMe(Title, Body, Icon);` is jquery custom function**